# WCF + net.tcp Communication Timeout problem

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding, net-tcp

I have some critical problem in my project. During transaction time with (wcf + netTCP) 
I was getting the exception is.

```
The communication object, 
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel, 
cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
```

In WCF service app.config add binding tag with timeout specification. But my transaction has been ended within 10 min. what was the problem..

```
 <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceSoap" closeTimeout="0:01:00" openTimeout="0:01:00" receiveTimeout="10:00:00" sendTimeout="10:00:00" allowCookies="false"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="b1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="infinite" sendTimeout="10:00:00"

transferMode="Buffered"

maxBufferPoolSize="524288"

maxBufferSize="65536"

maxConnections="10"

maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Any one help me !!!..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think its a timeout issue? The error message doesn't suggest a timeout has ocured. Could the server be throwing an exception?

I would strongly recommend setting up [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx). Its a bit involved but really worth doing as I've solved many obscure WCF issue with it.

Comment: Without seeing more of the code I don't know how I could solve this problem. There could be a serialization issue? You really need to setup WCF Tracing to further debug the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer but if you are using the client + server on the same machine you can use a named-pipe binding instead of netTcp

The binding section the configurations might look like this.

```
<netNamedPipeBinding>
  <binding name="infiniteOpenBindingConfig" receiveTimeout="infinite" closeTimeout="infinite">
  </binding>
</netNamedPipeBinding>
```

To keep the binding alive indefinitely the configuration above must be set both on server and client.

Comment: I am using server machine different places. may be i try to make http instead of netTcp

Comment: Any one have solution for this

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your netTcpBinding:

```
<reliableSession inactivityTimeout="infinite" enabled="true" />
```

And if that doesn't work, enable WCF tracing to find out what's killing it.